# celery eta argument is not respected in task signature

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, task

I have several tasks which should be sequently executed. I need to set dynamic timeout between execution of task_a and task_b.

I'd like to pass **eta** argument to task_b, not `time.sleep` inside task_a (ruins asyncronous approach) or calling task_b inside task_a (possible issues with code reusage).

```
task_a = task_a.s()
task_b = task_b.signature(
    args=(arg_a,),
    starkwargs={
        'eta': datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=dynamic_coefficient)  # not working, task_b is executed immediately. When I use 'options' keyword, I get "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'isoformat'"
    }
)
(task_a | task_b).apply_async(
    eta=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1)  # this does work, but useless for me as delays task_a, not task_b
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown), ETA is:

> a specific date and time that is the earliest time at which your task
> will be executed.

> eta must be a datetime object, specifying an exact date and time (including millisecond precision, and timezone information)

So it doesn't actually delay the execution of a task by *n* seconds/minutes/hours/etc., what it does is it just executes the task specifically at the target time. The solution I found with your problem is use `countdown` instead of `eta`.

**tasks.py**

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import time

from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks')


@app.task(bind=True)
def add(self, x, y):
    print(f"{datetime.now(timezone.utc)} Called add for {self.request.eta}")
    return x + y


@app.task(bind=True)
def mul(self, x, y):
    print(f"{datetime.now(timezone.utc)} Called mul for {self.request.eta}")
    return x * y
```

### Problem: Using ETA to delay executions

```
target_eta = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=3)  # ETA is 3 seconds from now. To emphasize, the ETA is with respect to NOW, not with respect to the end of the 1st task's execution.

task_a = add.signature((1, 2))
task_b = mul.signature((3,), eta=target_eta)

time.sleep(5)  # Now, we are already past the indicated ETA. Thus it would now be executed as soon as possible, which we don't want to but it was how we configured it.

(task_a | task_b).apply_async()
```

```
[2021-08-17 21:33:24,831: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.add[0058965a-f9da-47dc-8f40-e111deb9bfbb] received
[2021-08-17 21:33:24,832: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 2021-08-17 13:33:24.832190+00:00 Called add for None
[2021-08-17 21:33:24,832: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 

[2021-08-17 21:33:24,833: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task tasks.add[0058965a-f9da-47dc-8f40-e111deb9bfbb] succeeded in 0.0014381749997482984s: 3
[2021-08-17 21:33:24,834: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.mul[6df9a54f-04f3-4178-8d23-eb2bd9b9c47b] received
[2021-08-17 21:33:24,930: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 2021-08-17 13:33:24.930689+00:00 Called mul for 2021-08-17T13:33:22.814930Z
[2021-08-17 21:33:24,930: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 

[2021-08-17 21:33:24,931: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task tasks.mul[6df9a54f-04f3-4178-8d23-eb2bd9b9c47b] succeeded in 0.0004077819999110943s: 9
```

- As you can see, it isn't actually wrong that the 2nd task was called immediately because its ETA was `2021-08-17T13:33:22.814930Z` and the time at that moment was already past it at `2021-08-17 21:33:24,930`.
- Thus, it respected the ETA, only that we didn't see the supposed delay of 3 seconds because we are already past it.
- If you want to see the delay between the 1st and 2nd task, then you have to set the ETA to a later time with respect to the assumed end of execution of the 1st task, and not with respect to the current time.

### Solution: Using Countdown to delay executions

```
target_countdown = 3

task_a = add.signature((1, 2))
task_b = mul.signature((3,), countdown=target_countdown)

time.sleep(5)  # Doesn't matter, the countdown applies with respect to the end of the 1st task in chain

(task_a | task_b).apply_async()
```

```
[2021-08-17 21:38:17,659: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.add[5712dee5-3c07-4e85-87bd-154b8db41784] received
[2021-08-17 21:38:17,660: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 2021-08-17 13:38:17.660491+00:00 Called add for None
[2021-08-17 21:38:17,660: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 

[2021-08-17 21:38:17,662: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task tasks.add[5712dee5-3c07-4e85-87bd-154b8db41784] succeeded in 0.0016173230001186312s: 3
[2021-08-17 21:38:17,663: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.mul[12cc2749-8dbd-46c4-9e91-e0007fffd84e] received
[2021-08-17 21:38:20,798: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 2021-08-17 13:38:20.798231+00:00 Called mul for 2021-08-17T13:38:20.661087+00:00
[2021-08-17 21:38:20,798: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 

[2021-08-17 21:38:20,798: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task tasks.mul[12cc2749-8dbd-46c4-9e91-e0007fffd84e] succeeded in 0.0005633190003209165s: 9
```

- Now as expected, there is already a 3-second delay in-between the execution of the 1st and 2nd task.

Comment: My solution didn't work due to bug of serialization. Upgrading to Celery==4.3.1 solved this. Using countdown argument seems more appropiate to me, will try it a little bit later.

Comment: thx, the next time I should read documentation more thoroughly.